# A proof on number of solutions exceeding the degree of a congruent polynom - modulo a prime number

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to understand the proof of the following result:

> If $p$ is prime, and $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ with $f(x)= a_0 x^n + ... + a_n$
> Then, if the congruence equation has strictly more than $n$ solutions, the coefficients of $f(x)$ are multiples of $p$.

To understand the proof I concern myself only with the case $n=2$.

So let's say there are $3$ solutions $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

We can rewrite $f(x)$ as:

$f(x) = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2) + b(x-x_1) + c$

With $a=a_0$, $b=a_1 + x_1 + x_2$ and $c = a_2 +x_1 x_2 + x_1 b$

By plugging in $x= x_1$ in $f(x)$ we get that $c\equiv  0 \pmod p$ (i.e. $p \mid c$).

However, I get in troubles when plugging in $x=x_2$ (and plugging in $x=x_3$ as well).

By plugging in by $x= x_2$, we have: $p\mid b(x_2 - x_1)$

What I want to get is that $p\mid b$, so I need to prove that $p\nmid (x_2 - x_1)$

My atempt at proving $p\nmid (x_2 - x_1)$ has been to substract $a_0 x_1 ^2 + a_1 x_1 + a_2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ with $a_0 x_2 ^2 + a_1 x_2 + a_2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ but the squared terms are not very easy to handle.

If anyone could help me with this I would be grateful!

Thank i.a.

Comment: As in the dupes, if a quadratic has at least $2$ roots $\,r_1,r_2$ then iterating the factor theorem writes it as $\,f(x) = a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\,$ so if $\,r_3\,$ is also a root then $\,f(r_3)= a(r_3-r_1)(r_3-r_2)\equiv 0,\,$ so $a\not\equiv 0\Rightarrow \,r_3-r_1\equiv 0\,$ or $\,r_3- r_2\equiv 0,\,$ so every root is $\equiv r_1$ or $\,r_2,\,$ so there are at most $2$ roots.

Comment: I understand that your $a$ is not congruent to $0$. But what about $b=a_1 + x_1 + x_2$ ? How can we be sure that it's not congruent to $0$ ?

Comment: Said argument proves there are at most $2$ roots.  If you don't understand it then please explain what is not clear.

Comment: I don't understand where do you use that everything is modulo a **prime** number, a fact that my theorem has as a premise

Comment: Is "being a domain" connected somehow to the primality of $p$ ?

Comment: $bc\equiv 0\pmod{\!p}\!\iff p\mid bc\!\!\!\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm EL}\!\!}\iff p\mid b\,$ or $\,p\mid c\iff b\equiv 0\,$ or $\,c\equiv 0\pmod{\!p},\,$ by $\color{#c00}{\rm EL}$ = Euclid's Lemma and $p$ prime. Said in ring theory language: $\,p\,$ prime $\Rightarrow \Bbb Z_p \cong \Bbb Z/p\,$ is an [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain#:~:text=13%20External%20links-,Definition,0%7D%20is%20a%20prime%20ideal.), i.e. $bc = 0\Rightarrow b=0\,$ or $\,c = 0.\ \ $

Comment: OP, is the contrapositive of above, i.e. if if $\,r_3\not\equiv r_2$ or $\,r_1$ then $\,a\equiv 0\,$ so all coef's of $\,f\,$ are $\equiv 0.\ \ $